# Use term reference field in node--custom.tpl.php

Tags: entities

I am building a website with Drupal 7, this website contains a blog. For some reasons I use a custom content type for blog posts call bog_post. In this content type I add a "Term reference" field (is machine name is "field_blog_categories").

To custom the layout of blog post I override node--blog_post.tpl.php. My problem is to display the term reference field. When I print the php var corresponding to that field "$field_blog_categories" I get :

```
Array ( [en] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tid] => 8 ) ) )
```

As you can see the term name don't appear. I thought to get the name by tid. I try

```
taxonomy_term_load($field_blog_categories['en'][0]['tid'])
```

but it return nothing.

Any help to get the term name will be appreciate !

Comment: I make a mistake, actually 
`taxonomy_term_load($field_blog_categories['en'][0]['tid'])` works but I don't print the result... taxonomy_term_load() return an array which include the name. However thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `taxonomy_term_load()` return false then

- the supplied argument (tid) is either non-numeric
- Or there is no term with this id.

To check if there is any term against this id try

```
`taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array($tid), array());`
```

If `taxonomy_term_load_multiple()` returns empty array then it is clear there is no term with this `$tid`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate approach, you could try using the function

```
<?php
/**
 * Get a list of all taxonomy terms
 */
function taxonomy_node_get_terms($node, $key = 'tid') {
    if(arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {  
        static $terms;
        if (!isset($terms[$node->vid][$key])) {
            $query = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'r');
            $t_alias = $query->join('taxonomy_term_data', 't', 'r.tid = t.tid');
            $v_alias = $query->join('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'v', 't.vid = v.vid');
            $query->fields( $t_alias );
            $query->condition("r.nid", $node->nid);
            $result = $query->execute();
            $terms[$node->vid][$key] = array();
            foreach ($result as $term) {
                $terms[$node->vid][$key][$term->$key] = $term;
            }
        }
        return $terms[$node->vid][$key];
    }
}

/* just guessing at this function - it might need tweaking! */

function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $results = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node);
    if(is_array($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $item) {
           $variables['your_taxonomy_terms'][] = $item->name; 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Then you could call $your_taxonomy_terms from your page template and it should return the names.

This is all based on the thread here -> http://drupal.org/node/1072806